# How can I repair a git repository with a missing object?

Tags: git

My development repository at some point lost an object.

```
$ git fsck
fatal: failed to read object 2dddc84156fa30e4614a7ea5a1895885011b8db8: Invalid argument
$ git cat-file -t 2dddc84156fa30e4614a7ea5a1895885011b8db8
error: unable to find 2dddc84156fa30e4614a7ea5a1895885011b8db8
fatal: git cat-file 2dddc84156fa30e4614a7ea5a1895885011b8db8: bad file
```

A freshly cloned repository has that object.

```
$ git cat-file -t 2dddc84156fa30e4614a7ea5a1895885011b8db8
tree
```

I would like to keep my development repository, it has unpushed branches and stashes.

How can I patch that object into my broken repository?

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929674/what-can-i-do-with-git-corruption-due-to-a-missing-object

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you can try, is to get the file `.git/objects/2d/ddc84156fa30e4614a7ea5a1895885011b8db8` from the freshly cloned repository and copy it to your development repo ...

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't exist in the fresh repo.  `.git/objects/` contains an empty `info/` and `pack/pack-dce082ac46b5bd850378e93f384a1b8e01e3b87a.idx` plus `pack/pack-dce082ac46b5bd850378e93f384a1b8e01e3b87a.pack`.  `git unpack-objects -r < .git/objects/pack/pack-dce082ac46b5bd850378e93f384a1b8e01e3b87a.pack` claims it unpacked 100% but I can't find them.

Comment: OIC, I need to unpack them in a fresh repo.  Is there any harm in `cd /path/to/broken-repo;  git unpack-objects < /path/to/clean-repo/.git/objects/pack/pack-blahblah` to just get everything which might be missing or corrupted?

Answer (score 13):

I recently had a bunch of missing objects in a local repository and an uncorrupted reference repository to restore it from. Here's the magic I came up with that worked for me:

```
cd <path-to-local-repo>
git unpack-objects < <reference-repo-path>/objects/pack/pack-<hash>.pack
```

It turns out that all of the objects I needed were in a pack file in the reference repository instead of in separate "loose" object files. This simple incantation unpacks that pack file into the local database, filling in the holes. After doing

```
git gc
```

to cleanup any dangling commits (i.e. due to rebasing, amend commits, etc.) my *git fsck* is now clean.

Comment: Perfect! Worked really well! Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me as well, can confirm.

Answer (score 7):

It pretty much boils down to this: do you have a backup of that file (.git/objects/2d/ddc84156fa30e4614a7ea5a1895885011b8db8) anywhere? If you can find it, copy it back to your git repository and everything will be good again. In other words, do you know if the repository has been cloned? If it has, you will find that file in the clone's git folder and copy it to yours. If you have not cloned the repository, have you zipped it up somewhere? If you're on a mac, have you checked Time machine? If you're not on a mac, are you using something to backup your code?

It basically boils down to this: You need a backup of that file. Git is designed so that when this happens, you just use the backup (which is a clone of the repository) to restore the file. That said, the file name is based on an SHA1 hash, so if you can find that filename in anyone else's repository, chances are pretty good that you can use it in your own :)

It is usually good practice to always clone your repositories to another location, for safe keeping in case something like this happens. This is also why services like github and bitbucket are so popular.

You also probably want to look at this question: [How to recover Git objects damaged by hard disk failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801577/how-to-recover-git-objects-damaged-by-hard-disk-failure)

Comment: He stated that he has a freshly cloned repository (see 2nd code snippet). And just a simple thing: The git file name is sha1, not md5 :)

Comment: Thanks. Updated my answer :). Also, if your freshly cloned repository has that object, what @klaustopher has suggested will fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue because some objects in the old branches/tags are missing for unknown reasons. (I suppose it might relate to git gc, and these branches/tags are based on remote usually force-pushed refs)

So the solution is to remove these broken branches/tags.

```
$ git fsck --name-objects # find the broken refs
$ git for-each-ref
$ git update-ref -d xxx # remove the broken refs found

$ git branch -r | xargs -i git branch --delete --remotes {} # delete all remote branches locally
$ git tag -d $(git tag -l) # delete all local tags
```

Then re-fetch from remote:

```
$ git fetch origin --prune
```