# Heroku push gives unable to read error message

Tags: heroku, github

I have some issues with pushing to Heroku. When ever I try to push my application I get the error `fatal: unable to read {sha1 value}`.

The stacktrace is as following:

```
git push heroku master
Counting objects: 2066, done.
error: unable to find {sha1 value}
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1954/1954), done.
fatal: unable to read {sha1 value}
```

I don't have any issues pushing to GitHub, so I don't know if I might have corrupted something in my Heroku application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what `git fsck` returns, and see if you can copy the missing git object directly in the `.git/objects` on the heroku server.
That would be similar to the approach taken in "[What can I do with Git corruption due to a missing object?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4930967/6309)".

Comment: I get the error "broken link from tree {sha1} to blob {sha1} missing blob {sha1}". But how can this happen on Heroku and not GitHub? I thought you basically just pushed from your Master branch to Heroku?

Comment: How do I copy the git object directly to .git/objects, when Heroku doesn't have a FTP?

Comment: I think something was wrong with my machine locally, so I just cloned the solution again, and then got it to work.

Comment: @Dofs yes, this is the safest approach, when you cannot copy files over the remote git repo: clone that remote repo and work with that clone.