# Git corrupted repo: how to pick a git object from a clean repository

Tags: git, repository, corruption

This is one of the numerous questions regarding a Git repo that is corrupted, precisely a loose object that went wrong:

```
$ git gc
Counting objects: 3299, done.
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
error: unable to unpack 831a5d31af4a0af2f5a367689bee27a44efc22c9 header
Delta compression using up to 6 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3283/3283), done.
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
fatal: loose object 831a5d31af4a0af2f5a367689bee27a44efc22c9 (stored in .git/objects/83/1a5d31af4a0af2f5a367689bee27a44efc22c9) is corrupt
error: failed to run repack
```

Following existing answers on the subject ([How do I deal with corrupted git object files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4111728),  [How to fix corrupted git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18678853), or [What can I do with Git corruption due to a missing object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4929674)) I already removed the object `831a5d31` from the corrupted repository.

In my case I have a clone of the repository, that seems to hold the object I'm missing, but there's no file at `objects/83/1a5d31af4a0af2f5a367689bee27a44efc22c9`. How can I do to fix my repository?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**If the file exists elsewhere**

The object of the clean repository has been repacked, that's why it doesn't exist anymore as a file.

To restore it, first save it as a file, from the clean repository, with

```
git show 831a5d31af4a0af2f5a367689bee27a44efc22c9 > 831a5-file
```

Move `831a5-file` in the corrupted repo, and run

```
git hash-object -w 831a5-file
```

Make sure that the SHA1 given in the output is `831a5d31af4a0af2f5a367689bee27a44efc22c9`

This will store the object, and the repository is fixed!

**If the file does not exist elsewhere**

If the file doesn't exist elsewhere, i.e. the corruption occurred after commit but before you were able to push, there is a way to restore your repo and and re-commit the changes.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4263009/240430) to a related question.

Comment: This works for blob objects; is there a way to import/export tree objects?

Comment: To answer my own question, to do this for tree etc objects:
`git cat-file tree <hash> > temp`
`git hash-object -t tree -w temp`

Comment: Thanks, you saved my repo! Note that if your clean repo is from a different OS, the SHA1 may not match if line endings aren't the same across OSes. The solution still worked, though.

Comment: This didn't work for me but copying over the missing `object` files as specified by `git fsck` did