# git fatal: failed to read object xxx: Invalid argument

Tags: git

I am getting the following error if I pull for fetch from remote

```
$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 85, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (37/37), done.
remote: Total 85 (delta 63), reused 69 (delta 48)
Unpacking objects: 100% (85/85), done.
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
fatal: failed to read object 8b0fd4094630fea108b60faa15535ffbc85d87cb: Invalid argument
error: http://myremoterepo.com/project.git did not send all necessary objects
```

I can commit locally. When I check status:

```
> $ git status On branch vikas Your branch is based on 'origin/master',
> but the upstream is gone.   (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to
> fixup) nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25527812/git-corrupted-repo-how-to-pick-a-git-object-from-a-clean-repository) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254389/git-corrupt-loose-object)

Comment: When I opened a file `8b/0fd4094630fea108b60faa15535ffbc85d87cb`, its    `0000 0000` or `NULL NULL NULL...`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Finally I was able to fix this issue.
I think issue happened when my computer shutdown due to power cut.

I was able to commit any changes in any of my local branch. This means my pack file is no corrupted but some refs are invalid.

Back up your `.git` first. Then I use `git fsck` command

```
$ git fsck --full
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
error: unable to unpack 38fe6f16c7e8246d61150f0bc42629dbb532b5ce header
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
fatal: loose object 38fe6f16c7e8246d61150f0bc42629dbb532b5ce (stored in .git/objects/38/fe6f16c7e8246d61150f0bc42629dbb532b5ce) is corrupt
```

I deleted the file `.git/objects/38/fe6f16c7e8246d61150f0bc42629dbb532b5ce` and continuing these steps until I get following output:

```
$ git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (168543/168543), done.
error: refs/remotes/origin/staging: invalid sha1 pointer 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
error: refs/remotes/origin/development: invalid sha1 pointer 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
error: refs/remotes/origin/master: invalid sha1 pointer 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
error: bad ref for refs/remotes/origin/staging
broken link from  commit 8b0fd4094630fea108b60faa15535ffbc85d87cb
              to  commit bac9f287963b1abb9e4b376b44b4a6500018e9fe
Checking connectivity: 169821, done.
dangling blob 750718546640b5b14c19cbdb9958d7bcc4b1114c
dangling blob e313786318d4c76004728f15a25c6fa68c88b67e
dangling blob ee3fd85992b48173f6c344a9f4a2f9667d4e1940
dangling blob cd4898a3ec525e559292337c0bc6b68a77270b52
dangling blob 9973506f35af1bf4e7790be57b02c70852843f92
dangling blob 47ca4080b9a528efe23c9f7dce994815f5f9162a
dangling blob 39d6807d215a7e74fb987d951a90e1d3e24a97eb
dangling blob c0d650286c3702d56b827eded27eaa9515212847
dangling commit 53db70d776ec7a59c10db106ef2585abea1ffddd
...
```

Now I removed all three refs (`.git/refs/remotes/origin/master`, `.git/refs/remotes/origin/staging`, `.git/refs/remotes/origin/development`)

Voila! Now I was able to pull and push!

P.S. learned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12371337/415865)

Comment: After deleting those objects getting unresolved deltas for deleted objects

Comment: @Vicas: Can you please elaborate on what exactly did you mean by "...removed all three refs..."? Do you mean simply deleting these files? Deleting their contents?

Comment: @Vikas: Sorry, I misspelled... Please see above. Thanks!

Comment: Is it necessary to delete the references in .git/refs/remotes/origin? After following the first two steps I was able to run "git status" successfully.

Comment: after I've got only `dangling blob` logs I've runned `git prune` and all these logs gone away.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error while having [`Malwarebytes`](https://www.malwarebytes.com) running. A PC reboot did not help. Stopping the `Malwarebytes` process fixed it, though. Therefore, try disabling/stopping your virus scanner since that might also cause this problem.

Comment: Indeed. What a find. How Malwarebytes corrupted the HEAD of the master branch (local and remote) is a mystery. I wasn't even committing, fetching nor pushing (although PHPStorm was running). But it blue screened my Win10, a very rare occurrence. Time to kick Malwarebytes of my system.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey: Yes, it turns out it also blocks random websites such as my own which isn't very cool, plus the constant nags to buy premium haha. I guess it's good riddance.