# Git error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am getting
`Git error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method) fatal: failed to read object <hach>: Invalid argument error`
when I try do `$ git status`. How can I fix it?

Comment: I think this question has been already asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37739797/git-fatal-failed-to-read-object-xxx-invalid-argument.

Comment: I saw this question. And tryed.. I do $ git fsck --full, then delete error file, then when I do $ git fsck, I get "error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
error: unable to unpack a6cbf8ee9712f58427bba10bf816046315e2f506 header
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
fatal: loose object a6cbf8ee9712f58427bba10bf816046315e2f506 (stored in .git/objects/a6/cbf8ee9712f58427bba10bf816046315e2f506) is corrupt"

Comment: Are you sure you see it while running `git status`? Can you try a separate clone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git fatal: failed to read object xxx: Invalid argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37739797/git-fatal-failed-to-read-object-xxx-invalid-argument)

Comment: @Isergreev did you fixed it?

Comment: I have this issue now - did you ever resolve?

Answer (score 39):

1. Do a `git fsck --full`
2. Did it report a corrupted file?
3. If so delete the file, go back to step #1.
4. Do `del .git/index`
5. Do `git reset`

Answer (score 7):

I think it happened because maybe your computer or files were corrupted.

First back up your `.git` folder, then use `git fsck --full` command to check your file system then delete corrupt files and check it again until your problem disappear