# loose object objectName(stored in .git/objects/18/objectName) is corrupt

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am getting error when try to run git pull.

```
inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
fatal: loose object 18e4387980d72d03db058a8c24ce36335312c80c (stored in .git/objects/18/e4387980d72d03db058a8c24ce36335312c80c) is corrupt
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741683/git-error-inflate-data-stream-error-unknown-compression-method

Comment: Does the error also happen when you run `git fsck --full` If not, the remote repository is corrupted

Comment: Yes error occurred also, when run git fsck --full.