# git fatal: SHA1 COLLISION FOUND

Tags: git

I seem to have a corrupted repo that I have no idea how to fix...

```
$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 141, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (90/90), done.
error: unable to unpack ff7fca002656ad848c44bf134088d638a01d5217 header
error: inflateEnd: stream consistency error (no message)
fatal: SHA1 COLLISION FOUND WITH ff7fca002656ad848c44bf134088d638a01d5217 !
fatal: index-pack failed
Unable to write to standard output: The pipe is being closed.
```

And this is the output from the `fsck`:

```
$ git fsck
error: unable to unpack 024e257c1a13532e7d5579b0ea4bb5915d21e4a6 header
error: inflateEnd: stream consistency error (no message)
fatal: loose object 024e257c1a13532e7d5579b0ea4bb5915d21e4a6 (stored in super/sectet/path/to/repo/.git/objects/02/4e257c1a13532e7d5579b0ea4bb5915d21e4a6) is corrupt
```

Any ideas on how to approach this? I basically want to get whatever is in the remote and push my few commits on top of that.

Comment: Make a fresh clone of the remote, copy the changed files into fresh working copy, make a new commit and push.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864740) (possible duplicate, but I'll withhold judgement)

Comment: I already read that question, it's a bit unrelated I think :( Will try reapplying the commits on a fresh repo clone...

Comment: I'm pretty sure (but not positive) that this means you have a corrupted pack file.  The more interesting question is how to fix it, which I don't know.

Comment: Maybe related?: [How would git handle a SHA-1 collision on a blob?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9392365/456814).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the repo got corrupted by either EGit or SourceTree (which I use in parallel) and has nothing to do with actually hash collisions. I solved it, as suggested by comments, by cloning the remote as a new repo, and copying my changes over.

Comment: this isn't necessary. you can force the update of the remote refs.

Answer (score 47):

I ran into the same issue and ran:

```
git prune
git gc
```

which mentioned:

> error: bad ref for refs/remotes/origin/ticketName

So i removed the reference and that fixed the issue:

```
rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/ticketName
```

Comment: If the outdated refs get too annoying you can also do a git pull -f origin, which forces the update of the local db. Then also do the things stated in this answer.

Comment: I tried prune and got `error: could not read asdf34tuj3wg9wg09w5g fatal: bad tree object asdf34tuj3wg9wg09w5g` if i do gc I get `warning:reflog of 'refs/stash' references pruned commits` before those two lines and then `error: failed to run repack` after those two

Comment: For Windows: del .git/refs/remotes/origin/ticketName

Comment: I did this, removing the bad reference, and then had to do `git gc` again. Then I was able to fetch without problems.

Answer (score 6):

I have a similar issue and solved it by running:

```
$ git prune
Output: fatal: unable to parse object: refs/heads/prod-283
```

and just delete the reference above:

```
$ rm -f .git/refs/heads/prod-283
```

and finally I am able to run `git pull`

Comment: thanks, this solved an issue I had.  I did not want to clone the repository since it was too large.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following commnads:

```
git prune
git gc
```

and removed file .git\refs\remotes\origin\master (the one listed in error: bad ref)

and ran

```
git gc --prune=now
```

which fixed the issue.