# GIT: `window name "push_setup" already exists in parent

Tags: windows, git, github, gitlab

I'm banging my head against table for this issue. Actually, all of sudden my system (Windows 10) shut down. When it came on, following error in git pull arrived

> git fatal: SHA1 COLLISION FOUND

I sorted out this issue as per this link
[git fatal: SHA1 COLLISION FOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964033/git-fatal-sha1-collision-found)

Everything is working fine now except this following error on **PUSH** through Git GUI

> error: window name "push_setup" already exists in parent

[image: Git Push Error]

Comment: This is not a git error.  It is a window manager error.  Somehow your GUI is in a corrupt state. I am certain I don't know enough to fix it, but I'd add some details about your environment (OS, windowing system you're using, ...) and see if someone comes along that knows the right nuts and bolts.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'm using Windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After struggling with this issue from last couple of days I'm able to find the solution to this problem.

> Computer Restart will solve this issue. Restart your Windows and it will work.